# Github Actions: how to run a workflow created on a non-master branch from the workflow_dispatch event?

Tags: github-actions

Can someone help me understand the behaviour of the Github Actions tab? As somebody new to Actions working on a third party repo I would like to be able to create an action on a branch and execute it on the *workflow_dispatch* event.  I have not succeeded in doing this but I have discovered the following:

- The Action tab will change the branch where it finds workflows and action code based on the branch relating to the last executed workflow.  e.g. if some workflow is executed from the Action tab using the *Run Workflow* button and the *Use Workflow From* dropdown is set to some branch, Branch-A, then the contents of the *Workflows* panel on the left hand side of the Actions tab will be taken from Branch-A's version of *.github/*.
- The *This workflow has a workflow_dispatch event trigger.* text does not change with the branch. It seems to be taken from *master*. Alternatively, it may be being taken from the last set of results. I have not tested for that because either way it is not helpful behaviour.

The workaround is the execute on a push event which is OK but that seems out of kilter with Github's high standards of design.

Does the above sound a) about right and b) whichever way you look at it, not optimal behaviour? Or, is there a better approach to building and testing actions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

UPDATE: @hayesgm [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71057825/1089412) may be better choice since using `push`/`pull_request` workflow trigger will register new workflow in GitHub and then you can just remove unneeded `push`/`pull_request` events trigger and run workflow using `gh` command. It works without merging anything to default branch.

UPDATE 2: Seems like using @hayesgm way may not work for you if you expect to see "Run workflow" dropdown in GitHub UI for your not yet merged workflow. It will be available to see on workflow list in Actions tab and will be available to run using `gh` but not by using GitHub UI.

UPDATE 3: I could not find it documented anywhere but I think workflow is registered only if it exist on default branch or if it was run at least once on non-default branch. In case of non default branch, GitHub knows about workflow existence only when it has workflow run logs available. If you remove all workflow logs for it, then it will get unregistered and you cannot run it any more. This is not the case for workflows that exist on default branch. Those are always available even without any workflow run logs.

---

- Seems like it works as you described
- Text seems to change when you run workflow on non main branch and on this branch workflow name changed to something new...

This workflow name change is really strange. I couldn't find any docs describing this behavior.

### Testing workflows

One thing that needs to be done before testing is to actually add dummy workflow with same filename to `main`/`master`. Without this workflow won't appear in actions tab.

How to test:

1. Create dummy Readme.md and some dummy `.github/workflows/workflow.yml` to test:

   ```yaml
   name: Test run v1

   on:
     workflow_dispatch:

   jobs:
     test:
       runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
       steps:
         - name: Show environment v1
           run: env | grep ^GITHUB
         - name: Show ref v1
           run: echo "===============> Version from $GITHUB_REF"
   ```
2. Push to your default branch (probably `main` or `master`)
3. New action should appear there
4. You can now run dummy workflow

### Testing branch run:

1. Create new branch `test-branch` from default repo branch
2. Modify workflow file `.github/workflows/workflow.yml`

   ```yaml
   name: Test run v2

   on:
     workflow_dispatch:

   jobs:
     test:
       runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
       steps:
         - name: Show environment v2
           run: env | grep ^GITHUB
         - name: Show ref v2
           run: echo "===============> Version from $GITHUB_REF"
   ```
3. Commit and push to `test-branch`
4. Go to `Actions`
5. Click `Test run v1` and set `Use workflow from` to `test-branch`.
6. Click run workflow button

You should see different step names than in default repo branch workflow version and different `GITHUB_REF`.

The weird thing is that after running workflow on `test-branch` somehow without merging anything, my previous workflow (from default repo branch) changed name to new version.

[image]

Comment: It seems bug-ish so I think this works as the accepted answer.  Thanks for the analysis.

Comment: Seems like this weird name change bug was fixed because I did not see this behavior for some time now.

Answer (score 93):

You can run a workflow that is still in development in a branch `branch-name` from the command line, with Github CLI. The [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow#running-a-workflow-using-github-cli) says:

> To run a workflow on a branch other than the repository's default
> branch, use the --ref flag.
>
> `gh workflow run workflow-name --ref branch-name`

To list valid workflow names, use `gh workflow list`.

To add input parameters, run it like this:

`gh workflow run workflow-name --ref branch-name -f myparameter=myvalue`

Comment: Specifically for `workflow_dispatch` this won't work until the workflow has run once before. You can add a push event hook and then it will be activated after running once. Using `gh workflow list` you can see the job in the list once it has run once.

Comment: Hmm I didn't know that `gh` exists. Thanks. Sadly as @Dustin wrote. It is not working for newly created workflows never run before. Ive tested this by creating new workflow file on new branch and after running `gh workflow run workflow-test.yml --ref=feat/wf-dispatch-cli-test` I got only `could not find any workflows named workflow-test.yml`. Yet it sees old workflow on this new branch without problems.

Comment: To follow up on this: add a `pull_request:` to your workflow file and push that. It will register the workflow (you can view via `gh workflow list`). Then run `gh workflow run 'My Workflow Name' --ref branch-name`. Note there, that's the actual name of the workflow, not the name of the yaml file.

Comment: Having to add an event to the workflow to get it to run once is absurd! And I've noticed that this is not always the case. For instance, I can't find my newly added workflow in one repo, but in 10 other repos it's there and runnable (same workflow).

Answer (score 68):

You can run your workflow through the [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/), but you will first need to make sure it's run before.

```sh
gh workflow list
```

If your workflow isn't in that list (by name), then add `pull_request:` and create a pull request so that the workflow is registered, once.

```yaml
name: 'My Workflow'
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      parameter:
        description: My Parameter
  pull_request: -- Add this here
...
```

Once you've created a pull request, you should see 'My Workflow' when you run `gh workflow list`. Once that's done, you can remove the added line.

Finally, now run:

```sh
gh workflow run 'My Workflow' --ref my-branch -f parameter=value
```

This should run your workflow dispatch from a feature branch.

Comment: This is by far the best answer.

Comment: Instead of `pull_request` it would be even easier to just use `push` to trigger the first run from the branch.

Comment: We shouldn't have to do either of those things. If we add a `workflow_dispatch` event to a workflow, it should show up in the Actions tab / via `gh workflow list` immediately. (But it doesn't.)

Answer (score 22):

I'm seeing a lot of answers with adding `pull_request:`, but in my organization, we hold off on pull requests until we want review by others.

I think a better suggestion was made by @MEMark.

Add `push:` instead and just push once to your remote feature branch, then edit that line out. The action will be registered and you don't have to mess with master or any pull requests.

```
name: 'My Workflow'
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      parameter:
        description: My Parameter
  push: -- Add this here
```

Comment: Maybe you should start using Draft PRs? That will give you CI runs but without any reviewers being nudged. https://github.blog/2019-02-14-introducing-draft-pull-requests/

Comment: This is probably the _best_ answer as it doesn't require any meddling with the main/master branch to get the workflow in a runnable state.

Comment: It really is the easiest option! Just add `push:` and submit the changes. After that, the runner will start up. In the next commit, remove `push:` from your workflow. Voilà! Thanks you!

Comment: Good answer - if you do this though you will probably need to provide [default values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78124824/3059685) for your input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As an option you may fork third-party repository to yours, and do PR, merging to your main branch. After that you'll be able to debug workflow on your repository.

Another option is to add on: pull_requst: and test it by creating pull request.

Answer (score 0):

If you already modify your workflow, as shown in the other answers (suggesting to add PR) and then use `gh` cli, you might as well do this.

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch: {}
  push:
    branches:
    - features/myfeature
```

This way you dont need to use the cli.The pipeline will run once you push. Then you have to remove that branch trigger again, as you would do with the pr trigger.

So after all its still not ideal but at least you dont jump through more hoops using `gh` cli.

Answer (score -1):

Whether you use `on push:` or `on pull:`, you will likely need to provide default values for your input parameters (as they will all be set to `null` when the workflow is triggered).

For example:

```
name: 'My Workflow'
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      logLevel:
        description: Logging level
        type: string
        required: true
  push:

env:
  LOG_LEVEL: ${{ inputs.logLevel || 'DEBUG' }}
```

In the above example `inputs.logLevel` is null when run on push so the `||` expression defaults it to DEBUG.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73495922/3059685) for more details on how to set default values for input parameters.