# How to run a GitHub Action from a branch other than master?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a repository in GitHub and I want to create an Action to build a Docker image and push it to the DockerHub. I know how to do it but if I create the action in a branch other than master, GitHub does not run it.

This is a known problem ([Workflow files only picked up from master?](https://github.community/t/workflow-files-only-picked-up-from-master/16129)).

Any ideas to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github Actions: how to run a workflow created on a non-master branch from the workflow\_dispatch event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63362126/github-actions-how-to-run-a-workflow-created-on-a-non-master-branch-from-the-wo)

Comment: related: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25746#discussioncomment-3249051

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to the official GitHub Actions documentation ([Triggering a workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow)):

> The following steps occur to trigger a workflow run:
>
> 1. An event occurs on your repository, and the resulting event webhook has an associated commit SHA and Git ref.
> 2. The .github/workflows directory in your repository is searched for workflow files at the associated commit SHA or Git ref. The workflow files must be present in that commit SHA or Git ref to be considered.
>
>    For example, if the event occurred on a particular repository branch, then the workflow files must be present in the repository on that branch.
> 3. The workflow files for that commit SHA and Git ref are inspected, and a new workflow run is triggered for any workflows that have on: values that match the triggering event.
>
>    The workflow runs on your repository's code at the same commit SHA and Git ref that triggered the event. When a workflow runs, GitHub sets the GITHUB_SHA (commit SHA) and GITHUB_REF (Git ref) environment variables in the runner environment. For more information, see "Using environment variables."

Because of this, in order to test the workflows we need to perform a git action (ie. do `push`) in the created branch.

Comment: "if the event occurred on a particular repository branch, then the workflow files must be present in the repository on that branch." 

What I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 18):

> ```
> on:
>   push:
>     branches:
>       - "YOUR-TEST-BRANCH"
>   pull_request:
>     branches:
>       - "main" 
>     paths:
>       - ".github/workflows/test.yaml"
> ```

Answer (score 4):

What has worked for me (through trial and error)

1. Create an empty YAML file in the .github/workflows folder
2. Create a PR to move that file to your branch
3. In your branch, you can now do the necessary edits to get your GH Action up & running. NOTE: next to updating your YAML, you also need to make a change
   that *actually* triggers the workflow (I am using the below trigger, note the absence of the `'.github'` path trigger).

```
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'path/to/your/code/**'
```

Comment: 1. create an empty YAML file in the .github/workflows folder . This will not work for some one not having rights to directly check into default branch(when default branch is protected , which mostly is the case).

Comment: "Create a PR to move that file to your branch", this is hard to understand. You can't move files between branches (with or without PRs).

Comment: without create a PR you can create an empty workflow in the main/master branch than edit the same workflow in another branch. Than when you run, you'll can select in which branch run it

Answer (score 0):

Could it help if you add `workflow_dispatch:` as a trigger as well?

In that case you will be able to run the workflow manually on selected branch, from `GitHub>Actions` tab.

Comment: This doesn't work until the PR has been merged into the main branch, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: This is exactly the problem: The workflow does not appear on the Actions tab until it's in the main branch.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer.
You'll have a "Run workflow" button where you can select the branch where you want to run it on... -but you also need to have the proper protection rules set to allow running them from other than the main branch-

Answer (score 0):

As your question is not been addressed properly, I would like to describe.
If the problem is not yet solved,

> You just need to create a .github/workflows folder in the particular branch
> where you need to run Github Actions for.
> Create the yaml workflow file.
> Use the required branch name on: branches:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).