# How to test GitHub CI without tons of push?

Tags: git, github-actions

When I create a new workflow with GitHub Actions I have this cumbersome workflow:

1. Edit `.github/workflows/ci.yml`
2. `git commit --amend -mhope`
3. `git push -f`
4. Goto my browser, hit F5, click on the workflow and pray
5. Pull off some hairs from my old head and eventually goto 1

Is there any better alternative?

Comment: Have you checked the answer in the following thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59241249/how-to-run-github-actions-workflows-locally/

Comment: Indeed, so I know I cannot do it locally :)

Comment: Would it be an option to test it locally with act? https://github.com/nektos/act

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a [`workflow_dispatch`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) event to your `on:` directive. This allows you to trigger the workflow from the Actions panel in your repo. Once you've finished testing it, you can remove the trigger from your workflow YAML.

The trigger in the Actions panel looks like this (bottom right "Run workflow"):

[image]

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63480433, https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25746#discussioncomment-3249051

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the whole workflow locally there is beautiful [act](https://github.com/nektos/act) project.

For testing an individual GitHub Action there is [github-action-ts-run-api](https://github.com/cardinalby/github-action-ts-run-api) project.