# Schedule Trigger Github Action workflow with Input parameters

Tags: github-actions

I want to run my Github workflow two ways:

1. Manually by user
2. Cron job

Now, everything was running fine until I added input parameters. After that, the cron job is running but not picking default value.

Here is my yaml:

```
name: WebDriverIO Automation
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
        typeOfTesting:
          type: choice
          description: Select Type of Test
          default: 'stage-test-local-All'
          required: true
          options: 
          - stage-test-local-All
          - stage-test
          - stage-test-local-Sanity
          - prod-test
    branches:
      - workingBranch
      - JSNew
  schedule:
    - cron: "*/5 * * * *"
```

Comment: The inputs have nothing to do with the cron trigger. You're going to have to handle this in your workflow like "if typeOfTesting is not set, then set default".

Answer (score 20):

`inputs` are [available to workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#defining-inputs-for-manually-triggered-workflows) triggered by the workflow_dispatch event only (and to any workflows that are called by dispatched workflows).

When a workflow with inputs is run on a schedule (or on push/pull) all the input values are null.

For string and choice inputs you can use the `||` expression [operator](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#operators) to set the default value.

For boolean inputs you can use the `contains()` [function](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#contains) to set the default value.

For example:

```
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '15 0,18 * * 0-5'
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      logLevel:
        required: true
        type: string
      isTrueWhenScheduled:
        required: true
        type: boolean
      isFalseWhenScheduled:
        required: true
        type: boolean


jobs:
  test:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/run-job-with-params.yml
    secrets: inherit
    with:
      springProfile: 'production'
      logLevel: ${{ inputs.logLevel || 'DEBUG' }}
      isTrueWhenScheduled: ${{ !contains(inputs.isTrueWhenScheduled, 'false') }}
      isFalseWhenScheduled: ${{ contains(inputs.isFalseWhenScheduled, 'true') }}
```

In the above example the `logLevel` parameter is set to `DEBUG` when the workflow is triggered by cron. When the job is triggered by a dispatch event it gets set to the input value.

The `isTrueWhenScheduled` parameter is set to true when the workflow is triggered by cron. When the job is triggered by a dispatch event it gets set to the input value of either true or false.

The `isFalseWhenScheduled` parameter is set to false when the workflow is triggered by cron. When the job is triggered by a dispatch event it gets set to the input value of either true of false.

The `contains` function [casts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#contains) its first parameter to a string, and `null` is cast to the empty string `''`. When run on a schedule inputs parameters are all set to null. So:

| Run method | isTrueWhenScheduled value | input value resolves to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dispatch | **true** | `!contains('true', 'false')` = **true** |
| Dispatch | **false** | `!contains('false', 'false')` = **false** |
| Schedule | **null** | `!contains('', 'false')` = **true** |

And:

| Run method | isFalseWhenScheduled value | input value resolves to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dispatch | **true** | `contains('true', 'true')` = **true** |
| Dispatch | **false** | `contains('false', 'true')` = **false** |
| Schedule | **null** | `contains('', 'true')` = **false** |

Comment: is there a way to pass `DEBUG` with the `env` context so as to avoid hardcoding values?

Comment: with boolean input you can use something like `${{ inputs.myBoolean || github.event_name == 'schedule' }}`

Comment: Answer updated to show how boolean input parameters can be given both true and false values when run on a schedule.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another version that works with boolean inputs, and also supports setting the default to true:

```
name: Conditionally run a job

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      should_run:
        description: "Whether the job should run"
        type: boolean
        default: true
schedule:
  - cron: '0 * * * *'

jobs:
  my-job:
    name: This job runs on schedule or if inputs.should_run is true
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    if: ${{ !contains(inputs.should_run, 'false') }}
    steps:
    run: echo ok
```

This works as expected: the job always runs on schedule and when triggered manually it only runs if `inputs.should_run` is checked. That's because:

- If the workflow is run on schedule, then `inputs.should_run` is `null`.
- The `contains` function converts its argument to a string: `null` is converted to `''`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an env variable with a default value:

```
env:
  typeOfTesting: ${{ github.event_name == 'schedule' && 'stage-test-local-All' || github.event.inputs.typeOfTesting }}
```

then use `env.typeOfTesting` instead of `inputs.typeOfTesting`.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked

```
name: WebDriverIO Automation
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
        typeOfTesting:
          type: choice
          description: Select Type of Test
          default: 'stage-test-local-All'
          required: true
          options: 
          - stage-test-local-All
          - stage-test
          - stage-test-local-Sanity
          - prod-test
    branches:
      - workingBranch
  schedule:
    - cron: "*/5 * * * *"

...
..
..
   - name: Test
        run: |
          if [ ${{ github.event.inputs.typeOfTesting }} != "" ]; then
            npm run ${{ github.event.inputs.typeOfTesting }} 
          else 
              npm run stage-test-local-All 
          fi
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You could do this more succinctly with `npm run ${{ github.event.inputs.typeOfTesting || 'stage-test-local-All' }}`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set a separate workflow that uses a curl POST to trigger the desired workflow via dispatch. That way you could set up a payload with whatever variables/context you need. It's less than ideal to have two workflows for one job, but it gives you access to the full set of inputs.

Answer (score -1):

Several comments have mentioned that other answers don't work for boolean inputs, so here's one that does.

```yaml
name: Read a boolean input in a scheduled job

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 * * * *'
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      human:
        description: Did a human start this workflow?
        type: boolean
        default: true

jobs:
  report-boolean:
    name: Report boolean state
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      BOOLEAN_STATE: ${{ !!(inputs.human) }}
    steps:
      - name: Output boolean
        run: echo "'${BOOLEAN_STATE}'"
```

Results:

- I dispatch the workflow and leave the input box checked -> 'true'
- I dispatch the workflow and uncheck the box -> 'false'
- The schedule fires -> 'false'

If you want the variable to be true for the scheduled job, use one exclamation mark instead of two (`${{ !inputs.whatever }}`).

Comment: But the solution also needs to work when the workflow is run 'Manually by user'. So `${{ !inputs.whatever }}` just negates whatever value is provided when run manually, which is definitely not what you want.